# cocos2d screen orientation problems

Tags: iphone, ios4, rotation, cocos2d-iphone, screen-orientation

I am using the standard rotation code present in cocos2d 0.99-rc0 to support portrait + two landscape modes. I am showing the menu in portrait mode, and then the screen rotates to landscape for the actual game. Problem is that when i go back to portrait, the whole mainmenu scene is off by half the screen, like someone had moved the anchor point or something.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible simple solution would be to apply the orientation at the start of the scene then after wards re-apply the positions of your menu items so that its all aligned.

I do the following to change the screen orientation:

Firstly, the first line goes inside the init method I set a timer to start after a quick 0.5 seconds. Putting it in a timer means in my game the scene transition (fade) works smoothly, the screen doesn't rotate/snap round then, but you probably won't need to use this.

```
[self schedule:@selector(rotate:) interval:0.5];

-(void)rotate:(ccTime) dt{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [self unschedule:@selector(rotate:)];
}
```

The key line is below, you don't necessarily need the timer:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Of course you can alter this bit for different orientations:

```
CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
CCDeviceOrientationPortrait
CCDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like a real hack, but hey - if there are no better solutions, then this is the best solution! Thanks for sharing, i'll have a look into this again once i complete some other stuff.